# .load() doesn't like my slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a slider showing posts from a category. When the user clicks "next category", the content goes left and the new content is loaded along with it's slider.

This .load() is making a request to the same page, with different parameters (don't really know if this is relevant to the question).

Problem is, the loaded slider doesn't work. You can see it [here](http://gop.com.pt/projectos.php?catProj=1), click on the top right arrow and you'll see my problem.

This is the script I'm using:

```
function carousels(){
  if ($("#projectos-carousel").length) {
    $("#projectos-carousel").carouFredSel({
      items: { visible: 5 },
      circular: false,
      infinite: false,
      auto: false,
      prev: { button    : "#prev-proj" },
      next: { button    : "#next-proj" },
      pagination    : "#pager-proj",
    });
  }
}

...

$('.right-trigger').click(function () {
  var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #container';
  $('#container').attr('id','to-go');
  $('#to-go').css({'position': 'absolute'});
  $('#wrapper').append('<div id="newcontainer"/>');
  $('#newcontainer').load(toLoad, function () {
    $('#newcontainer').append($('#container').children()).css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': '942px'});
    $('#to-go, #newcontainer').animate({left:'-=937'},600, function () {
      $('#to-go').remove();
    });
    $('#container').remove();
    $('#newcontainer').attr('id','container');
    searchform();
    triggers();
    carousels();
  });
  return false;
});
```

searchform() and triggers() functions work but not carousels(). I've already tried using setTimeout(); with carousels() in the last part of the code but it only works on this [example](http://www.hypersand.eu/testing/), not where I really want to.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: That's the "(don't really know if this is relevant to the question)". The request is "projectos.php?catProj=1".

Comment: Inside the `carousels` function, add this as the first line `alert($("#projectos-carousel").length);` and post the results.

Comment: not related to the question, but a suggestion. The page loads slow the first time. The images on the bottom (the slider) are scaled down to 162x260 from higher res. Maybe make those images that size for there. Also, the big images are too high res (some are like 1MB), try saving as JPG with, say, 90% quality, will probably make them much smaller, and the page faster to load (and usually no noticeable difference in quality). Just suggestions.

Comment: @leo.vingi the result is always 1, even when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work for me. One problem that I see in your code that will manifest itself as a bug in Internet Explorer is that you have a trailing comma on this line:

```
pagination    : "#pager-proj",
```

Removing the comma may fix everything for you. Additionally, I would suggest wrapping all of your object properties in single or double quotes. For example, the previous line would become:

```
"pagination": "#pager-proj"
```

Comment: You say it works for you, that's odd. Here it doesn't. Did you clicked on the top right arrow (the white one)?